# Getting 401 (Unauthorized) hitting ticketmaster api after logging in

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am building an artist search React app that hits the Ticketmaster API and should return the results before logging and after logging in.

I am getting 401(Unauthorized) after logging in.

search.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Form, FormControl, Button}  from 'react-bootstrap';
import './style.css';



class SearchField extends Component {

    state = {
        search: ""
    };

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        this.setState({[name]: value.toLowerCase()});
    };

    apiCall = () => {

    const ticketmasterURL = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?keyword=";
    const searchKey = process.env.REACT_APP_TM_KEY;
    const term = this.state.search.split(" ").join("+");
    axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + ticketmasterURL + term + "&apikey=" + searchKey)
        .then(res => {
            this.props.history.push({
                pathname: "/events/",
                search: `?${this.state.search.split(" ").join("+")}`,
                state: {data: JSON.stringify(res.data._embedded.events)}
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };


    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.apiCall();
        //set the redirect state to true
        this.setState({redirect: true});
    };


    render(){
        return (
            <div className="search-container">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FormControl 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Search" 
                            name="search"
                            value={this.state.search} 
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <div className="searchbtn-container">
                            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


export default withRouter(SearchField);
```

app.js

```
import setAuthToken from './_helpers/setAuthToken';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "./actions/authAction";


if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);

  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  Store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    Store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    window.location.href = "/login";
  }
}
```

setAuthToken.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
    }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

I think I localized the issue to setAuthToken function in app.js because it works without it but am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the type of the token, so:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token;
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749 (Section 7.1)

Comment: That's it. I couldn't figure it out because when I consoled logged the token, it showed "Bearer" followed by the token. Why do I need to add the type of token again?